# Integration testing on live test website, restoring the data after test suite completion

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, selenium, integration-testing

I want to write integration/automated test cases using selenium of live website say testing.example.com. This site is staging website of example.com.

When i run test cases, new data is created, update, deleted. After completion  of the test suite, i want to restore the database to the state where it was before running the test cases.

So for example state of database before running test cases --> s1
and state of database after running test cases --> s2

I want the database to go back to s1 state.

I am using rails framework and mysql/pg database

One solution could be taking dump of the database before running the test cases and then restoring the data after test cases run is completed.

What could be other solution?

Thanks

Comment: I think That's only solution which you have mentioned. Take database backup and then restore it after test completion. OR you can set dummy database and configure it when running test and after test completion configure actual database.

Comment: Will it create issue in indexing ??

Comment: I don't think that it can create any issue with existing indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly that solution until the database got to big and the procedure to  long time.

So I changed it to a type of rollback.

As a part of the setup in
Main class called by all test cases

```
  def run_once_beginning
    DEBUG("start","Running start function")
    DefaultDatabase.prepare_rollback
    DefaultDatabase.resetDB
  end

  def run_once_end
    DEBUG("start","Running end function")
    DefaultDatabase.drop_all_triggers
    DefaultDatabase.resetDB
  end

  def setup    
    if(State.instance.started == false)
      State.instance.started = true
      run_once_beginning
      at_exit do
        run_once_end
      end
    end
  end
```

DefaultDatabase.rb

```
def prepare_rollback

   query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `changes` (`table_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`table_name`))"
HandleDB.sendQuery(query)

   query = "show tables;"
   tables = HandleDB.sendQuery(query)
   exclude = ["phpsessions", "cameras", "changes", "connections", "sysevents"]
   triggers = "";
   tables.each{ |name|
     if (exclude.index(name) == nil)
       triggers += "DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ins_#{name};"
       triggers += "CREATE TRIGGER ins_#{name} AFTER INSERT ON #{name}
                 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
                 INSERT IGNORE INTO `changes` VALUES ('#{name}');
                 END;"
       triggers += "DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS up_#{name};"
       triggers += "CREATE TRIGGER up_#{name} AFTER UPDATE ON #{name}
                 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
                 INSERT IGNORE INTO `changes` VALUES ('#{name}');
                 END;"
       triggers += "DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS del_#{name};"
       triggers += "CREATE TRIGGER del_#{name} AFTER DELETE ON #{name}
                 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
                 INSERT IGNORE INTO `changes` VALUES ('#{name}');
                 END;"
     end
   }

   setup_connecion = Mysql.new(Constants::DB["ServerAddress"],"root", Constants::DB["Password"],
  Constants::DB["Database"],Constants::DB["ServerPort"], nil, Mysql::CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS)

   setup_connecion.query(triggers)

# Clear out all the results.
   while setup_connecion.more_results
     setup_connecion.next_result
   end
   query = "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS RestoreProc;"
   setup_connecion.query(query)

# This is a mysql stored procedure. It will use a cursor for extracting names of
# changed tables from the changed-table and then truncate these tables and
# repopulate them with data from the default db.
   query = "CREATE PROCEDURE RestoreProc()
     BEGIN
       DECLARE changed_name VARCHAR(60);
       DECLARE no_more_changes INT DEFAULT 0;
       DECLARE tables_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM changes;
       DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET no_more_changes = 1;

       OPEN tables_cursor;
       FETCH tables_cursor INTO changed_name;

       IF changed_name IS NOT NULL THEN
         REPEAT
           SET @sql_text=CONCAT('TRUNCATE ', changed_name);
           PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
           EXECUTE stmt;
           DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

           SET @sql_text=CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', changed_name, ' SELECT * FROM default_db.', changed_name);
           PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
           EXECUTE stmt;
           DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

           FETCH tables_cursor INTO changed_name;
         UNTIL no_more_changes = 1
         END REPEAT;
       END IF;

       CLOSE tables_cursor;
       TRUNCATE changes;
   END ;"

   setup_connecion.query(query)
   setup_connecion.close
end

def drop_all_triggers
    query = "show tables;"
    tables = HandleDB.sendQuery(query)
    triggers = ""
    tables.each{ |name|
      triggers += "DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS del_#{name};"
      triggers += "DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS up_#{name};"
      triggers += "DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ins_#{name};"
    }

    triggers_connection = Mysql.new(Constants::DB["ServerAddress"],"root", Constants::DB["Password"],
                     Constants::DB["Database"],Constants::DB["ServerPort"], nil, Mysql::CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS)

    triggers_connection.query(triggers)
    triggers_connection.close
  end

def resetDB
    restore_connection = Mysql.new(Constants::DB["ServerAddress"],Constants::DB["User"], Constants::DB["Password"],
      Constants::DB["Database"], Constants::DB["ServerPort"], nil, Mysql::CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS)
    restore_connection.query("CALL RestoreProc();")
    restore_connection.close
  end
```

For this to work a copy is needed of the original database in the state you want it to return to named "default_db".

"Exclude" are tables which will not be changed